# How to display a pdf file on the foreground of a web application

Tags: javascript, file, servlets, pdf, web-applications

I would like to know, how to display a PDF file on the foreground of a Java Servlet web application? For example, at GMail, you can open an attached file on the foreground. What I want to do is

- a user clicks a button and a pdf file is displayed on the foreground
- a user clicks a button located at the corner of the foreground, and a pdf file is disappeared

Comment: To render the PDF on the client-side you could use http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ and for the "foregroud effect" one of the gazillion "Lightbox" scripts (modal overlays).

Comment: or you can use div with `position: fixed`